# number validation via JS on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, validation, onclick, onsubmit

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong... can't seem to get this form to show the alert when I don't enter anything and submit...

```
        <script>
                    function validate() {
                        var n1 = document.forms["GoToPage"]["page"].value;
                        if ( isNaN(n1) ) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            alert("Must be a Number!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
        </script>
<form name="GoToPage" method="GET">
<input type="number" min="1" max="1000" name="page" size="4" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return validate();" />
</form>
```

Comment: The logic is wrong, *isNaN* returns true if converting the value to number results in NaN. If the user enters say "2" (noting that the value of a form control is always a string), then `isNaN('2')` will return `false` and execution goes to the else branch. Also, validation should be on the form's submit handler, not the button since you can submit a form without clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

Well your logic is wrong as mentioned by *RobG*.

```js
function validate() {
  var n1 = document.forms["GoToPage"]["page"].value;
  if (n1.length>0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Must be a Number!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="GoToPage" method="GET" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" name="page" size="4" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I checked the code and it worked as expected. I think as input type is number, js will take it as number. So, I think NaN was always escaping.

Comment: The logic is wrong, *isNaN* returns true if the value is NaN, so the form should not submit. If the value is not NaN (i.e. the value can be converted to a non–NaN number by `Number(value)`), then the form should submit but instead it throws up an alert.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was just saying that his code worked, at least shows alert which he was not getting. I did not see the logic!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BiploveLamichhane - I have tried with your `n1.length>0` logic but somehow (and I don't understand why) my form is still submitting even if I don't enter anything... you can see it at the bottom of this page: chaindlk.com/reviews/

Comment: I have editted the answer now. You would be able to do now... but its kind of a same..

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna check n1 is a number, use

```
if ( !(isNaN(n1)) ) {
    return true;
 }
```

it will return true if n1 is a number.

if you didn't send anything, isNaN will be false.

```js
console.log(!(isNaN(''))); //if you use the code above
console.log(isNaN(''));
```

use this for return false if you didn't send anything

```
if ( !(isNaN(n1)) && n1!='' ) {
    return true;
}
```

It will be look like this

```html
<script>
  function validate() {
      var n1 = document.forms["GoToPage"]["page"].value;
      if ( !(isNaN(n1)) && n1!='' ) {
          alert("It's a Number!");
          return true;
      } else {
          alert("It's not a Number!");
          return false;
      }
  }
</script>
<form name="GoToPage" method="GET">
<input type="number" min="1" max="1000" name="page" size="4" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return validate();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Warmoa but I still get no alert... and with your second piece of code I get an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ) {' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`  error

Comment: I've added my edit to your code in my answer, try it

Comment: I cannot explain why @warmoa but when I try it on my server the form still gets processed, the alert does not show... it's almost like javascript is being ignored...